# Functions missing in production slot after deploying to staging slot

Tags: azure-functions, azure-deployment-slots

I have a function app with 2 slots - staging and production. Both staging and production slots have some functions.

I have the following YAML task to deploy to staging deployment slot:

```
- task: AzureFunctionApp@1
  displayName: 'deploy ${{ parameters.name }} function app (staging)'
  inputs:
    appType: 'functionapp'
    azureSubscription: sub
    appName: 'appname'
    Package: 'name.zip'
    deploymentMethod: 'runFromPackage'
    deployToSlotOrASE: true
    slotName: 'staging'
    resourceGroupName: 'rg'
```

After deployment I see functions inside staging slot but I see NO functions (or ONLY one function with the same name as function app) inside production slot. What am I missing?

[image]

UPDATE:

I have the following resources in bicep file before the above YAML step:

```
resource functionApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2018-02-01' = {
  name: name
  location: location
  kind: kind
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', servicePlanName)
    clientAffinityEnabled: false
    httpsOnly: true
    siteConfig: {
      use32BitWorkerProcess : false
      appSettings: secretSettings
    }
  }
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
}

resource functionAppSlot 'Microsoft.Web/sites/slots@2018-11-01' = {
  name: name
  kind: kind
  location: location
  properties: {
    clientAffinityEnabled: true
    enabled: true
    httpsOnly: true
    serverFarmId: resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', servicePlanName)
    siteConfig: {
      use32BitWorkerProcess : false
      appSettings: secretSettings
    }
  }
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
}
```

While creating the function app, does it delete all the existing functions in production slot?

Comment: do you have auto swap enable ? or are you swapping the slot manually ?

Comment: I swap slots manually after deployment to staging slot

Comment: so you deploy / swap and no function in the production slot ? did you check staging functions before swapping

Comment: No - I deploy to staging and functions are deployed to staging, but I see functions in production missing (earlier production had some functions. Why did it change while deploying to staging. That’s what I am not sure about). After swap, I see functions in production but functions are missing in staging.

Comment: Yeah when you swap whatever was in production go to staging an vice versa. could you confirm that prior to deploying the prod was all good ?

Comment: yes prod was all good. Not sure if I'm missing something in app settings.

Comment: @Thomas Could you please check my updated section in the question?

Comment: Redeploying your bicep file wont remove your code.

Comment: So in prod let say you have a function name `function1`, you can have the same in staging  `function1`. After deployment and manual swap, you can see the function in staging slot but nothing in the production slot ? Could you check the zip file you are deploying, maybe the zip is incorrect and doesnt not deploy anything

Comment: No let me correct it - So in prod I have a function named function1, I have the same in staging function1. After deployment, I can see the function in staging slot but nothing in the production slot. After swap, I see function in production slot but nothing in staging slot.

Comment: Similar to https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/82452

Comment: Oh so in your ARM do you have the appsetting `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` ?

Comment: Initially I had that setting but I kept on getting bad gateway error during deployment, so I removed that setting.

Comment: Try to re add it in your.bicep file, should be equal to 1

Comment: should I set it for app settings of both staging & production slots?

Comment: yep `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1` for both slots

Comment: One quick question - I have a YAML task for creating function app in Incremental mode. Could that be a reason why the functions getting removed during each deployment?

Comment: incremental should work tbh

Comment: I still see the same issue after adding WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1 for both slots .